# Correct way to mutate a component property in blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I have two components, `Child.razor` and `Parent.razor`.

The `Child.razor` HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="@Text" />
```

The `Child.razor` C#:

```
[Parameter] public string Text { get; set; }
```

And the `Parent.razor` HTML:

```
<Child @ref="child_1" />
<Child @ref="child_2" />
<Child @ref="child_3" />
```

`Parent.razor` C#:

```
Child child_1;
Child child_2;
Child child_3;

void SetText(Child item, string text)
{
    item.Text = text;
}
```

I get a warning on the `item.Text = text`:

> Warning BL0005: Component parameter 'Text' should not be set outside of its component.

After some googling, I found this question: [BL0005 - external parameter usage - why is a warning for that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58852101/bl0005-external-parameter-usage-why-is-a-warning-for-that)

The answer is great, but it does not provide an alternative (the linked content on github is also not very helpful).

What is the correct way to mutate a component parameter from the parent?

**EDIT**

To clarify a bit more: I know I could use binding, but I need to be able to change the value inside the `SetText` method, passing the Child I want to mutate as a parameter. The problem with binding is that the variable is not tied with the component. In other words: with the referente to the Child, I am not able to know which binding string I should set.

For example:

```
<Child @ref="child_1" @Text="binding_1" />
<Child @ref="child_2" @Text="binding_2"/>
<Child @ref="child_3" @Text="binding_3"/>
```

`Parent.razor` C#:

```
Child child_1;
Child child_2;
Child child_3;

string binding_1;
string binding_2;
string binding_3;

void SetText(Child item, string text)
{
     // which binding string should I set?
}
```

I can visualize some funky code, creating a `Dictionary<Child, string>` to correlate the Component to the binding string, or something like that, but... really?

Comment: Well i think it is obvious. `<Child @ref="child_1" @Text="ParentSth" />` then modify `ParentSth` property

Comment: @Eldar How to use binding in my example, inside the SetText method?

Comment: Sorry i missed the binding part at first comment. You can bind your parentProperty to child parameter like this : `<Child @ref="child_1" @bind-Text="ParentSth" />` and when you change `ParentSth` property in your parent it will reflected to the child.

Comment: @Eldar thank you for your comment. Please see my edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a property of type **Child** in the parent component
pass a reference of the parent component (this) to the child component property of Parent type. Now the child component hold a reference to the parent component, and it can add itself (again using this) to the parent. Now you have a reference to the child component, and you can set its Text property to something interesting. I hope I'm clear, if not I'll post code to reflect this. The following code works...

### Child.razor

```
<input type="text" value="@Text" />

@code
{
    [Parameter] public string Text { get; set; }
    public void SetText(string text)
    {
        Text = text;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    [ParameterAttribute] public Parent Parent { get; set; }
    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            Parent.AddToParent(this);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note** that the original component parameter Text's value assigned in the parent component (`Text="Some Text"`) is not visible in the text box
because immediately after the Parent's SetText method calls the Child's SetText method, which in return assign the value passed to it to the Text property, and thus the value seen in the text box is "new text"

### Parent.Razor

```
<Child Parent="this" Text="Some Text" />

@code{
    public void AddToParent(Child child)
    {
        string text = "new text";
        SetText(child, text);
    }

    void SetText(Child item, string text)
    {
        // which binding string should I set?
        item.SetText(text);

    }
}
```

### Usage

```
<Parent />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I find the need to exchange references between parent and child very unfortunate for Blazor, but I believe that this is the best way to do that.

Comment: Yes, this is how Steve Anderson created the Tab sample.

Comment: Steve Sanderson ;-)

Comment: Architecturally this sounds like a bad solution. The parent and the child component would both depend on each other and it wouldn't be possible to substitute either for other components.

Comment: How can I detect which ParameterAttribute param is changed in Blazor, or can I get the old value or new value of the same param?

Answer (score 0):

Мaybe it can help:

1. declare the global delegate type

```
    public delegate void OnInput(string v);
```

2. Child

```
    <input type="text" @bind-value="@Value" />
    
    @code {
        [Parameter]
        public OnInput oninput { get; set; }
        [Parameter]
        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                return v;
            }
            set
            {
                v = value;
                if (oninput!=null) oninput(value);
            }
        }
        private string v;
    }
```

3. Parent

```
    <Child Value=@binding_1 OnInput=@((__v)=>{binding_1=__v;})/>
    <Child Value=@binding_2 OnInput=@((__v)=>{binding_2=__v;})/>
    <Child Value=@binding_3 OnInput=@((__v)=>{binding_3=__v;})/>
    @code {
        public string binding_1=new string("default value 1");
        public string binding_2=new string("default value 2");
        public string binding_3=new string("default value 3");
    }
```