Getting Warning BL0005 when modeling data for EditForm in Blazor
I am doing something like this in the Blazor HTML section...
<EditForm EditContext="editContext" OnValidSubmit="SubmitQuery">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.ValidationSummary />
    <InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="@Model.Selection">
        <InputRadio Value="FindGuestDisplay.Selections[0]" /><label>@(FindGuestDisplay.Selections[0]):</label>
        <br />
        <label class="fglabel">First Name:</label><InputText @bind-Value="@FirstName" style="width:300px" />
        <label class="fglabel">Last Name:</label><InputText @bind-Value="@LastName" style="width:300px" />

...
and in the code section I am wrapping my model setters in local properties like so....
private string FirstName { get { return Model!.FirstName ?? ""; } set { Model!.FirstName = value; } }
private string LastName { get { return Model!.LastName ?? ""; } set { Model.LastName = value; } }

I did this because I get the errors throughout the whole code if I use the Model properties directly and this limits the warning to just the setters.
Note that this code works but I want to do this the right way, warning free.
By the way, I am doing this almost exactly the way that Microsoft's example for using Edit form says, so how can I get rid of this error? Is there a proper alternative I should be using?
here is my model declaration within my Blazor component (not set or passed in from outside):
FindGuestDisplay Model { get; set; }=  new ();
the model gets passed into the editContext here:
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
editContext = new(Model);
editContext.OnValidationRequested += HandleValidationRequested;
messageStore = new(editContext);
}

here is my class definition:
public class FindGuestDisplay
{
    [Parameter]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Email is too long.")]
    public string Email { get; set; } = "";
    [Parameter]
    //[Required]
    [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "First Name is too long.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = "";
    [Parameter]
    [StringLength(25, ErrorMessage = "Last Name is too long.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; } = "";
    [Parameter]
    [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Cell Phone is too long.")]
    public string CellPhone { get; set; } = "";
    [Parameter]
    [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Home Phone is too long.")]
    public string HomePhone { get; set; } = "";
    [Parameter]
    [StringLength(25, ErrorMessage = "Work Phone is too long.")]
    public string WorkPhone { get; set; } = "";

    [Parameter]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Business Name is too long.")]
    public string BusinessName { get; set; } = "";
    [Parameter]
    public string? BarcodeID { get; set; }

    public string Selection { get; set; } = "Enter Guest Information";
    public static readonly List<String> Selections = 
    [ "Enter Guest Information", "Find Web GuestPass", "Find Business" ];
}

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!
From my understanding, I am doing this the proper way. Is this just a bad warning?

Why are you defining your model properties with [Parameter]?  "From my understanding, I am doing this the proper way."  No, that's plain wrong.  Where did you see information to tell you to do that?  Produce a [MRE] to show what you are trying to do.  You're form shows no input controls for the model.  See this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58874588/13065781.

Why do you wrap model properties in component?

The parameter was something I got from a tutorial on Youtube. But you are correct I don't need it to be a parameter. I'll remove that and see what happens.

Thank you! Removing the parameter tag from my data model properties did the trick. Seems pretty obvious in hindsight but I couldn't find the answer in my research.

Here is a pattern I use:
@page "/mypage"
@if (Model == null)
{
   return;
}
<div>First Name: @Model.FirstName</div> Model is not null here -> no warnings
@code
{
    MyPageModel? Model {get; set;}
    //Instantiate the model anywhere...
}

If the model is passed as a Parameter, I use required keyword and [EditorRequired]:
[Parameter, EditorRequired]
public required MyPageModel {get; set;}


Thanks. I think I have it now. I appreciate your help.
